# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException error in host

Tags: laravel

Hi I have a login page in my laravel project that's  work connect to a laravel route 
 with ajax 
 I test my project in localhost that ok and we have had no problem in localhost
now I upload my project to a real host and when ajax sended In login page 
this error showed to me
[image]

note: I used csrf_token() in sending ajax

Comment: Open trace and see where the exception come.

Comment: can you share code